# powershell -which AD user has no profile path

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Some users in our organization has not configured profile path, in the AD. (under Remote Desktop Services Profile.)

I want to get all this user, so I wrote this in Powershell:

```
Write-Host "Running..."
$users=Get-ADUser -Filter *
foreach($user in $users)
    {

        $userDN=(Get-ADUser $user).DistinguishedName
        $Userinfo=[ADSI]"LDAP://$userDN"
        $TermianlPath=$Userinfo.TerminalServicesProfilePath

        if ($TermianlPath -eq $null)
            {
                $UserSAMName=$user.SamAccountName
                Write-Host "User $UserSAMName has no Terminal path." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            }
    }

Write-Host "Completed." -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

The check of "if ($TermianlPath -eq $null)" doesn't give anything...

Someone can help please ?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Server are you querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two issues with what you are trying to do.

1. `$Userinfo` does not have every ad attribute exposed as a property. By default PowerShell allows you to request non existent variable properties without error.
2. The attribute you are looking for is [not called `TerminalServicesProfilePath` in Server 2008+](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb6e172e-459b-42fa-928c-f6688bdafde6/unable-to-retrieve-terminal-service-properties-from-native-adds-object-directoryentryinvokeget?forum=csharpgeneral). If you look at ADSI edit or other means you will see these attributes

```
msTSAllowLogon
msTSHomeDirectory 
msTSHomeDrive 
msTSProfilePath
....
```

So what you should be doing involves this which would return the profile path or null if it did not exist.

```
$userInfo.psbase.InvokeGet("msTSProfilePath")
```

Using that something like this should work

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | 
    Where-Object{
        -not ([ADSI]"LDAP://$($_.DistinguishedName)").psbase.InvokeGet("msTSProfilePath")
    } | ForEach-Object{ 
        Write-Host "User $($_.SamAccountName) has no Terminal path." -ForegroundColor Cyan    
}
```

The where clause will allow any user that does not have a profile path set to pass down the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is a bit odd with $null. A lot of times something can be returned not as a $null but as an empty string. Try checking for both $null and for "".

Also, instead of using two empty quotes, "", you could use [string]::IsNullOrEmpty() as well for any variable that could be a string.